# Qt QFileDialog input field - tab complete like shell

Tags: qt, file, autocomplete, path, pyqt

I've got a basic PyQt QFileDialog file browser goin in Python, Kubuntu.

My issue is I would like the "tab key" in the file input to act as tab-complete does in a shell.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

From a UI/UX standpoint are you sure that's what you want? In forms and dialogs tab has traditionally meant go to next field. You might be confusing the user. Or you might start a revolution in User Experience for forms :-)

Just curious if that's what you really want?

Comment: yeah its what i want ;) 
this particular UI im replacing is JUST a unix style path input field. leaving out typical tab-behavior for a UI here is not a problem. what i really want for my script is the ability to query the available paths using the text that is typed in, and if the user presses tab - it completes for them if there is only one option.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to subclass the QFileDialog, and change the behavior. It will probably not be easy.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't made use of PyQt yet, but I think the QCompleter class might be most of the way to what you want:

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/tools-completer.html

I don't know if it tab completes or if that's something you'd have to add yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can actually, i don't see any access to the input field in the documentation of [QFileDialog](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qfiledialog.html).  Qt is fairly aggressive at hiding implementation detail from it's users. You might be able to do this by taking the implementation of QFileDialog (C++) and modify it for your purpose.

Comment: If you take this solution beware of licensing issues. Anyway, I believe you have to do this or roll your own file dialog.